# Can you say "I dare say yes" when someone asks you a question?

Tags: word-usage

When someone asks you a question that requires a yes or no answer, Is it grammatically correct to say:

> I dare say yes?

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to say "I dare say it is." ( or "he does", or whatever "yes" represents). As [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/i-dare-say-i-daresay) says, _I dare say_ is used with _a statement_.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks. they say you should add a sentence after it and I believe "yes" to be a complete sentence. So it is not meaningless even though not idiomatic?

Comment: That phrase can be found in more dictionaries without the space:  "daresay".

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Thanks for your comment, Jack! I appreciate it.